# Forgot Password Patterns or techniques? ¿pattern names?

Tags: design-patterns, authentication, forgot-password

I friend of mine just posted on Buzz a question:

> When you hit "Forgot your password" in most of the pages, they
>   will send you an email with a link
>   (most of the time it will expire after
>   sometime) to reset your pass. In most
>   cases that link includes something
>   like a UUID. Is there a name for this
>   technique? Making an expirable url /
>   link? The way I will do this is just
>   generating a UUID, or something
>   simpler and doing all the expire stuff
>   programmatically. I'm wondering if
>   there is a name for this kind of
>   technique?

After reading his question, I'm now curious about the same,  this technique already got a name, or better, it's already considered as a pattern for the global community?

Comment: I thought it was another form of authentication?  The UUID is to prove that you are the user who wanted the password reset, so...

Comment: What i want to know if there exist a name for this pattern...

Comment: I suggest removing the "java" tag since the question is not related to the language and adding the "user-experience" tag since it's relevant to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call this [Self-service password reset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-service_password_reset) with authentication token.

---

**Resources :**

- [www.goodsecurityquestions.com](http://www.goodsecurityquestions.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the name of the UI pattern is "Password reset pattern" or "Forgot password pattern".

One of the worst implementations is where you answer a "security" question to reset your password because they are really insecure, as the link pointed by Colin Hebert [says](http://www.goodsecurityquestions.com).

One of the best implementations is Amiando's asking for user e-mail address and new password and then sending confirmation via email to confirm new password. More info on [this](http://aralbalkan.com/3274) blog.

It is very important that the user confirms his identity via email or other personal medium like SMS on cellphone (less common).

Other examples of implementations of this pattern [here](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-great-examples-of-a-forgot-password-UX-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic pattern I'm going with in my application:

1. User enters username or email and clicks "Reset password"
2. One-time token url emailed to that user (this can expire after a few
   hours).
3. User *must click on link* in email.
4. User is then emailed a randomly generated password upon confirmation

They can then login with this password or change it once they login (optional)

I think this is best from a security perspective as well as easy to use for the end user.